# How can I request an already logged in user to confirm password to enter a specific page in django?

Tags: python, django, authentication, passwords

I'm working on a django application. The application has a dashboard. How can i make it so that everytime the user wants to access the dashboard, he/she has to confirm their identity, with the same password they use to log into the same application?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

#Verify that the USERNAME and PASSWORD combination exist USING THE **AUTHENTICATE** METHOD,

**Views.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

#IN YOUR CASE get the pwd using forms or something,

instance_password = request.post.get('the_pwd_field')

user = authenticate(request, username= request.user.username, password= instance_password)

if user is not None:
    # REDIRECT TO THE DASHBOARD
else:
    # FAIL CASE SCENARIO
```

Answer (score 0):

In views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password

form = YourFormForPassword(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    currentpasswordentered = form.cleaned_data.get("try_password")
    currentpassword = request.user.password

    authenticate_user = check_password(currentpasswordentered, currentpassword)

if authenticate_user:
    # REDIRECT TO THE DASHBOARD
else:
   #Redirect to other page or keep same login page
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want, user to enter credentials explicitly before accessing the dashboard, then you have to return the "form" that accepts creds from user, when they try to access the dashboard.

```
def dashboard_login_view(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DashboardLoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('dashboard_login_username').lower()
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('dashboard_login_password')
            authenticated = check_password(password)
            if authenticated:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard_view'))
            else:
                messages.error('User is not authenticated.')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))
    else:
        context['form_one'] = DashboardLoginForm()
 
    return render(request, 'dashboardlogin.html', context)
```